# ARM Cortex M0+ USART and Multiplexing (SAMD10D14A)

Tags: arm, microcontroller, cortex-m, samd10

I am starting to work with the ARM Cortex M0+ cores, specifically the [SAMD10DA14](https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/microchip-technology/ATSAMD10D14A-MUT/ATSAMD10D14A-MUTCT-ND/5226478) and I am a little confused on how the Multiplexing pins are defined. On page 13 of the datasheet it has a breakdown of the Multiplexing listing for SERCOMX PAD[X] configurations. What I am not clear about is which PAD[X] are used for which configuration and function.

For example on the [SAM D10 XPlained Mini](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/SAM-D10-Xplain-Mini_Design-Documentation.zip) it shows the Rx and Tx of the USART comming from the ATMega32 to Pins 9(PA10) Tx and 10(PA11) Rx. These are defined in the Multiplexing Table as SERCOM0/PAD[2](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/SAM-D10-Xplain-Mini_Design-Documentation.zip) for Tx and SERCOM0/PAD[3] for Rx.

What I am not clear about is PAD[2](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/SAM-D10-Xplain-Mini_Design-Documentation.zip) always used for Tx and PAD[3] for Rx or as long as your using the same SERCOM[X] the pins can be mixed? I have searched through the Datasheet and can't seem to locate anything further on how the multiplexing pins are used. There is all sorts of information regarding the Address's, Bits and other uses but I can't find anything describing the actual physical setup and configuration.

I am also unsure about how the Waveform Outputs (WO) are defined. The Datasheet specifies that there are up to 8 WO's for the Timer Counter Controls (TCC) that are defined as WO[0] - WO[7]. The confusing part is there seems to be a couple of duplicates (TCC0/WO[0]) on PA04(Pin 4) and on PA14(Pin 11). Are these pins interchangeable or is one defined as a Interrupt Pin or some other function?

I apologize if this has already been asked somewhere, I would actually be surprised if there wasn't something already, but I couldn't locate it.

Comment: You can configure which pad is used for Rx and Tx. See table 25-8 and 25-9 on page 457. They call it "receive data pinout" and "transmit data pinout". Similar registers exist for SPI and I2C. So its multi-step process: Chose a specific SERCOM (there are 3), configure it for USART, configure the pads to be used (CTRLA.xx), route it to pins (PORT configuration).

Comment: @Codo If I understand correctly the setup is fairly flexible, for example the TCC are available from PA04-PA-23 and PA30-PA-24 so I can choose which ever pins are available but can only have W0-W7 enabled, for example I can not use both PA08 and PA22 (TCC0/WO[4]) as TCC0, correct?

Comment: You probably can. The last sentence on page 615 says: "One signal can be mapped on several pins." The PINCFG and PMUX registers also allow it.